# How to blur background image.?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blur

I am rendering a image in cycles.The question is how to blur background in blender cycles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use dept of field to blur the background. It is located in the camera properties panel. [image]

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways of doing this, here is how I would do it.

First, go to the *render layers* tab of the properties view and enable an *environment* pass under the *passes* rollout.
[image]

Then make sure you have checked *transparent* under *render* properties > *film* rollout.
[image]

Then you can blur just the environment pass in the compositor and mix it into the render using a *mix node* based on the alpha.
[image]